# Parallel Co-ordinates Plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to plot a parallel co-ordinate plot for a dataset mtcars. I want to set a variable on color. I used the code :

```
 library(GGgally)
 ggparcoord(data=mtcars, columns=1:10 , groupColumn=11)
```

It generated the graph but all the lines are in shades of blue. However I have trouble comprehending the graph and making observations due to similar colors used. How can I introduce a different set of colors like blue, green and red etx for the same variable.

Comment: That's because column 11 ("carb") is a numeric variable, so ggplot uses continuous shading. Convert it to a factor and you'll get discrete shading. For example: `mtcars$carbF = factor(mtcars$carb);
ggparcoord(data=mtcars, columns=1:10 , groupColumn="carbF")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ggparcoord()`'s coloring function for this by turning the grouping-column into a factor.

```
mtcars[,11] <- as.factor(mtcars[,11]) 
ggparcoord(data=mtcars, columns=1:10 , groupColumn=11)
```

[image: This is a bit more colorful]